# Show One Column Data as Two Columns in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have saved language string resources in a table. These are saved as row wise for each culture code
as shown below:

```
 ---------------------------------------------
  CULTURE      KEYFIELD                 VALUEFIELD
 ----------------------------------------------

   en-US       AadhaarUID              Aadhaar UID
   en-US       Abbreviation            Abbreviation
   en-US       Abbreviation_CD         Abbreviation
   en-US       Abbreviation_DM         Abbreviation
   en-US       AboutPortal             About Portal
   hi-IN       AadhaarUID              आधार यूआईडी नंबर लिखें
   hi-IN       Abbreviation            संक्षिप्त
   hi-IN       Abbreviation_CD         संक्षिप्त
   hi-IN       Abbreviation_DM         संक्षिप्त
   hi-IN       AboutPortal             पोर्टल के बारे में
```

I want to display the column `ValueField` as two columns one for english and one for hindi. Number of rows for each culture will be equal.`PFFIELD` will be only from `hi-IN`.

Means Output should be as:

```
   -------------------------------------------------------
     PKFIELD   ENGLISH                         HINDI
    ------------------------------------------------------
        2       Aadhaar UID                 आधार यूआईडी नंबर लिखें
        4       Abbreviation                 संक्षिप्त
        6       Abbreviation                 संक्षिप्त
        8       Abbreviation                 संक्षिप्त
        10       About Portal                  पोर्टल के बारे में
```

How can I do this in SQL?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean `PKFIELD` is from `hi-IN` only?

Comment: Means..When I show result in Table. I have to edit only `hi-IN` values..`en-US` will be readonly.To edit `hi-IN` I need their `_PK` field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    PKField = MAX(CASE WHEN Culture = 'hi-IN' THEN PKField END),
    English = MAX(CASE WHEN Culture = 'en-US' THEN ValueField END),
    Hindi = MAX(CASE WHEN Culture = 'hi-IN' THEN ValueField END) 
FROM temp
GROUP BY KeyField
```

Comment: thanks. I need one more field to display i.e. `PrimaryKeyField`. `PrimaryKeyField` will be only from 'hi-IN' How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

And for good measure, you can also pivot - this will be more useful for larger numbers of languages:

```
SELECT [KEYFIELD], [en-US], [hi-IN]
FROM Abbreviations
PIVOT
(
  MAX([VALUEFIELD])
  FOR [CULTURE] IN ([en-US], [hi-IN])
) y;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4df5/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  [English] = E.[ValueFiled]
        ,[Hindi] = H.[ValueFiled]
FROM    [TableName] E
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM [TableName] H WHERE H.[Culture] = 'hi-IN') H
        ON E.[KeyField] = H.[KeyField]
WHERE   E.[Culture] = 'en-US'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.valuefield as "ENGLISH", b.valuefield as "HINDI"
from tab a, tab b
where
    a.keyfield = b.keyfield
    and a.culture = 'en-US'
    and b.culture = 'hi-IN'
;
```